# AngularJs ui-grid how refer column defination name to add filter?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

1. I want to set filer to a column in ui-grid dynamically using gridOptions.columnDef using column name. Right now I am only able to use number as a key.
2. How can I add multiple filters on a single column dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a custom filter for your grid item and then in the logic there you can do whatever you want. Something like this

```
    field: 'myfilteredfield',
    filter: {
        condition: myCustomFilter
    }
```

and in your controller

```
    $scope.myCustomFilter = function(searchTerm,cellValue,row,column) {


    };
```

Look here for details  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef